# Running unittest from directory called "test" in root by using PyCharm not working

Tags: python, pycharm, python-unittest

I have the following folder structure

```
test_foo (project root)
|──test
   |──test_foo.py
```

The content of test_foo.py is

```
import unittest

class MyTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_something(self):
        self.assertEqual(True, False)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

If I right click on **test_foo.py** in the [Project tool window](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/project-tool-window.html) and select **Run 'Unittest in test_foo...'** the test runs properly, as it should. However, if I right click in the code on the class name (*MyTestCase*) or on the method (*test_something*) and select **Run 'Unittest for MyTest...'** I get a popup saying

```
Error running 'Unittest for MyTestCase':
Can't resolve MyTestCase. Try remove configuration and generate it again.
```

I have tried removing the configuration and regenerating a new one but it didn't help.

If I rename the folder from *test* to anything else it works to run the test by right clicking on the class/method name.

Is this a feature or a bug? How do I fix this without renaming the folder?

Answer (score 0):

Found one work-around:

I had marked the directory called 'test' as "Sources root". By unmarking the directory as sources root it works to both run the test from both the project tool window and by right clicking on the class/method name:

**Right click on the 'test' directory in the project tool window -> Mark Directory as -> Unmark as Sources root**